# thyristor works like a diode independent from gate signal

Tags: circuit-analysis

I wanted to model a thyristor and I modeled it by a circuit like this:
[image]

In the negative loop of Vsin thyristor passes the signal without even receiving any pulse from above circuits. and funnier , input signal affects gate voltage significantly. here is gate voltage and output signal(output is the red line and gate voltage is the green one. I'm not allowed to post more than 2 links):
[image]

I also replaced the gate signal with a pulse generator and it still does not work.

I simulated similar circuit with matlab and it worked perfectly in negative loop of input voltage.
what could be the problem?

---

Edit 1:

These are the result when I simulated same circuit with Matlab:[image]

Output:

[image]

---

Edit 2:

@Transistor : Here is a schematic and its results (The blue trace is input gate pulses, the red one is the out put and the the green one is gate voltage) :[image]
[image]
As you can see, the gate signal is approximately the same as the input signal although the pulses are generated at the right time. and the out put is still the same.
and for (3): actually i want to use a microcontroller to generate gate pulses. I think there wont be any problems.
and thank you again for your responses.

Comment: Post the images again.

Comment: Have you tested the spice model? never trust a spice model until you've verified it with a test.

Comment: Thanks for your response. What do you mean by testing my spice model? How can I test it?

Comment: It is not clear from Edit 2 whether or not you think the circuit is now working properly. From what I can see it is not working properly. When the pulse is off V2 is held at 0 V. That means that whenever the cathode is pulled negative the thyristor turns on (because the gate is positive with respect to the cathode) without waiting for the pulse. You can see that the pulse does nothing.

Comment: You are right. circuit does not work as it should. And that is exactly my problem: why does the thyristor turn on without waiting for the pulse? it shouldn't.

Comment: Go to chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62737/thyristor.

Comment: @Ahmadreza.2ahm Look at your schematic "Edit 2" with pulse generator. It is perfectly clear that you drive your thyristor with a pulse with respect to GND, not to thyristor's cathode. When AC source is in it's negative phase the cathode of the thyristor is negative and gate is 0. This way gate's voltage is greater than cathode's and thyristor turns on.

Comment: @Transistor :  I have less than 20 reputation to go to that chat. I'm not allowed to :(

Comment: @TodorSimeonov : I think you are right. what should I do? should I add cathode voltage to the pulses using OpAmp?

Comment: Why are you asking what to do? If you have ground referenced trigger signals then you ground the cathode of the SCR as shown at the very start of my answer. If you can't ground the cathode then you use one of the solutions to couple the trigger to the floating SCR as I have already described. Swap the position of SCR and R10. Cathode to ground.

Comment: @Transistor : I tried to ground the cathode and it didn't work(It just works in figure (b) of your answer.my question is about figure (a)) . I coupled the trigger to cathode , it worked . However that's not an option since practically, I use a 220v as input. Adding gate signal to such a voltage will burn down the thriystor.

Comment: Right. I think you do not have enough understanding at this time to work on a 220 V project with SCRs. You have failed to understand that the trigger signal is relative to the cathode and not to ground. You are asking about using op-amps to add cathode voltage to the pulses. (How would that work at 220 V AC?) You need to start studying again and look at how others have designed SCR circuits. Read http://www.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics/application_notes/switching_thyristors/littelfuse_thyristor_phase_control_using_thyristors_application_note.pdf.pdf several times. Forget your design.

Comment: OpAmp idea was for small signals like in schematic(although it still may be high).I have enough understanding to know 220v is impossible to use as an input to an Opamp . I'm looking for ideas to run such a circuit with 220v input. Again : It is not my design. It is what I found in the books. So there should be a way to make it all work. I will definitely read your reference. thanks for your help. I'm really glad that I finally found out what was wrong with my circuits.Again, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have not analysed the whole schematic but I suspect that your thyristor is not configured correctly.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2gJzH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) What you did. (b) What you intended.*

Normal configuration is shown in Figure 1b. By raising the gate voltage with respect to the cathode you can trigger the triac.

In Figure 1a you are holding the gate steady and pulling the cathode high and low.

---

> And here is also a link: pantechsolutions.net/powerelectronics-tutorials/… – Ahmadreza.2ahm.

[image]

*Figure 2. OP's reference circuit. Note how there is no indication of how the gates are triggered.*

[image]

*Figure 3. SCR pulse transformer generates a trigger signal relative to the cathode. Source: [All About Circuits](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/semiconductors/chpt-7/silicon-controlled-rectifier-scr/).*

Your referenced article does not make clear that gate trigger is referenced to the cathode. If the cathode is connected to circuit ground (Figure 1b) then the trigger can be referenced to circuit ground. If not, then an isolated gate trigger is required.

Figure 3 shows one means of generating this. There are others including opto-isolators with photo-diodes which generate the trigger voltage.

---

Your Edit 2 still won't work. When the pulse generator is off V2 is held at 0 V. That means that whenever the cathode is pulled negative by the AC supply the thyristor turns on (because the gate is positive with respect to the cathode) without waiting for the pulse. You can see that the pulse does nothing.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3AF32.png)</sup>

Comment: thanks for your response. I believe,in my circuit, when trigger signal is applied to the gate, if the input voltage is negative, means when thyristor's cathode voltage is higher than its anode,  thyristor should turn on.

Comment: Generally, I want to have 2 thyristors in both directions to control input voltage. I have no problems controlling SCR in figure 1b.

Comment: (1) "*when thyristor's cathode voltage is higher than its anode, thyristor should turn on.*" Incorrect. Thyristor conducts from anode to cathode when triggered. Anode voltage must be higher. (2) "*In the negative loop of Vsin thyristor passes the signal without even receiving any pulse ...*" The gate is held at positive voltage all the time. Even with Q1 on it can't go below zero. That means that when the cathode goes negative the thyristor is triggered. (3) Did you make up this thyristor configuration or did you copy an existing design?

Comment: +1 for @Transistor comment. Maybe the second OpAmp must be powered with -10V (or better some more like -15V) instead of GND, but ... anyway this design does not look reliable.

Comment: @Transistor : sorry for the mistake about cathode and anode. I think when Q1 is turned on, the current which goes through the gate is so low that it couldn't feel it ( something about 0.2mA ). And as I told, i tried a pulse generator instead of all those circuits , and I still get the same results.

Comment: @TodorSimeonov :Thanks for your response, the circuits above the Thyristors are just simple schmitt trigger and monostable multivibrators. I replaced them with a pulse generator and got same results. I think there is something wrong with the Thyristor modelling.

Comment: You didn't answer my comments (2) or (3). Can you post a link to where this thyristor arrangement came from?

Comment: @Transistor: For comment (2), I answered that I replaced gate signal with a Vpulse to make sure gate's voltage reaches zero.And for comment (3), I copied an existing circuit which I found in a book written in my language.You can also find it in "Power Electronics written by daniel w. hart" . And here is also a link: https://www.pantechsolutions.net/powerelectronics-tutorials/single-phase-ac-phase-controlled-rectifier-using-tms320f28027f

Comment: (2) You'd need to show that on a schematic. (3) Your reference material doesn't explain how to trigger the gate. You have designed an incorrect way of doing this. See the update. I do not use MathLab so I don't know what assumptions the block diagrams make on the circuit simulation.

Comment: @Transistor:thanks for editing. I can not see your new comment.